# What is the correct method to redirect to the returnurl after logging in to an MVC ASP.Net application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-routing

Here is my login controller

```
        // POST: /Account/Login

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string ReturnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("invalid", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");

            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

When I start debugging this is the url on the login page:

```
http://localhost:8085/MobileApprover/Login/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fMobileApprover%2f&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
```

and this is the form I am using to post

```
<form class="form" action="/MobileApprover/Login/Login?ReturnUrl=<%=Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]%>" method="post">

<input type="text" class="span12" name="UserName" placeholder="User Name" />
<input type="password" class="span12" name="Password" class="" placeholder="Password"/>

<label class="checkbox"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" class="" /> 
Remember Me? 
</label>                   
<button type="submit"">Login</button>        
       <%:
          Html.ValidationSummary()   
       %>
```

After logging in I am at this url:

```
 http://localhost:8085/MobileApprover/Login/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fMobileApprover%2f&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#/MobileApprover/Login/Login?ReturnUrl=/MobileApprover/
```

I would like to be at this url http:localhost:8085/MobileApprover because when I type in that url (when debugging) the home controller correctly displays the view.

What am I doing wrong at this point? I believe the issue is related to the return url and how I am handling it but I have tried to

```
return Redirect(ReturnURL)
```

but that does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually cleaned up my code slightly and was able to get

```
Redirect(ReturnUrl);
```

to work, or you can use

```
            Session.Clear();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

For a sign out function